# puppet server puppet apply node definitions remotely from server

Tags: centos7, puppet, puppetmaster

i have setup puppet server agent setup.
I am using puppet version 4 for both server and agent.
I have my node definitions.
I can run puppet agent -t to retrieve the node definitions from puppet server.
I see on puppet enterprise there is an option to apply node definitions remotely by running puppet job on server.
does the non enterprise version have something similar to push out the node definitions from server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much as "pushing" a catalog. (There is nothing on the client-side listening for an incoming connection.) What it is doing is remotely triggering a Puppet Agent run out-of-band.

You can do this with a simple Bash script and SSH, but most people doing it frequently will want to wrap it with an orchestration tool such as Bolt or Ansible. (Which happen to work via SSH, but are more polished solutions.) I think Puppet Enterprise still uses Mcollective, but this isn't the easiest thing to integrate into Puppet open-source. (YMMV)